# zend framework 2 list modules in layout

Tags: layout, module, zend-framework2

I want to have a plug-in system (like wordpress ) , How can I list my admin controller in layout.phtml ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You have all kinds of questions. Do you want to know how to pass a variable to a layout? Or how to work with events? Or how to get a list of all enabled modules? Or, do you simply want a link on your homepage to your admin interface?

Comment: being more specific , I want to know how to list all my modules and show their names in layout.phtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of modules if available in the module manager (`Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager`). You can get the module manager via the service locator. For example in your controller:

```
class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $manager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ModuleManager');
        $modules = $manager->getLoadedModules();
    }
}
```

The controllers have access to the layout (and its parameters) via the `layout` controller plugin.

```
$this->layout()->modules = $modules;
```

An alternative is that you create a view helper. In this view helper, you get the module manager and then return the list of modules.